# Service Activator is not getting invoked

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I am trying this use case:
Poll for a message in a queue->transform the message->Call a method with the transformed message.

## Here is my code

```
    <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
            destination-name="test"
            channel="jmsInChannel"/>
    <channel id="jmsInChannel"/>
    <channel id="consoleOut"/>
    <int:transformer input-channel="jmsInChannel" ref="xmlMsgToVORPojoTransformer" output-channel="consoleOut">
    </int:transformer>

    <beans:bean id="xmlMsgToVORPojoTransformer" class="com.order.jmspublisher.ValidateOrderMessageTransformer">
        <beans:property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
   </beans:bean>

   <beans:bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <beans:property name="classesToBeBound">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.order.jmspublisher.ValidateOrderResponseType</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <logging-channel-adapter id="consoleOutloggerChannel" channel="consoleOut" log-full-message="true" level="DEBUG"/>
     <int:service-activator id="sa" input-channel="consoleOut"   output-channel="someChannel" method="handleVOR">
        <beans:bean id="vorActivator" class="com.order.jmspublisher.VORServiceActivator"/>
    </int:service-activator>
```

## My Transformer code is as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
       public Message transform(String message)
       {
           try {
              XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
              XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource(new StringReader(message)));
              xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to Envelope tag

              while(xsr.hasNext() ) {
                   int next = xsr.next();
                   if(next == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT)

                      if(xsr.getLocalName().equals("ValidateOrderResponse"))
                      {
                          break;
                      }

                }
             ValidateOrderResponseType vor = (ValidateOrderResponseType)marshaller.unmarshal(new StAXSource(xsr));
             return MessageBuilder.withPayload(vor).build();
          } catch (XmlMappingException e) {
              return MessageBuilder.withPayload(e).build();
          } catch(Exception e){
             return MessageBuilder.withPayload(e).build();
            }
       }
```

========================================================================
My service activator method code is as follows:

```
public class VORServiceActivator {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VORServiceActivator.class); 
    @ServiceActivator
       public String handleVOR(ValidateOrderResponseType vor)
       {
          logger.info("vor information received and invoke some services here....\r\n"+vor);
          return vor.toString();
       }

}
```

=========================================================================

My service activator method is not getting called. But my transform is getting called and I can see the same in logs.
Please help me to know where I am going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<channel id="consoleOut"/>` is a `DirectChannel`; you have 2 consumers subscribed to the channel (logging adapter and service activator).

The default dispatcher will distribute messages to these competing consumers in round-robin fashion; so each will get alternate messages.

You need to change `consoleOut` to a `<publish-subscribe-channel />` if you want both consumers to get all messages.

[You can read about channel types here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html).

Comment: Thanks Gary. I removed logging adapter in SI xml and the service activator got called. Thanks a lot.